# error: operand must be a register in range [d0, d15]

Tags: gcc, arm, simd, inline-assembly, neon

recently I have some issues when I try to optimize a conv operation， the error is： 
           operand must be a register in range [d0, d15]
              "vmla.s32  q8, q12, %f18[0]    \n"

k0_0123，k0_4567.. are all int32x4_t vectors, I just have no idea how to fix this error

```
                          "0:                             \n"
                            "pld        [%5, #128]          \n"
                            "vld1.s32   {d14-d15}, [%5]     \n" 
                            "pld        [%6, #128]          \n" 
                            "vld1.s32   {d16-d17}, [%6]     \n"   
                            "pld        [%7, #128]          \n" 
                            "vld1.s32   {d18-d19}, [%7]     \n" 
                            "pld        [%8, #128]          \n"                               
                            "vld1.s32   {d20-d21}, [%8]     \n"                                                                                                                                         

                            "pld        [%1, #64]          \n"
                            "vld1.u8    {d8}, [%1]         \n" 
                            "vmovl.u8   q4, d8             \n" 
                            "vext.16    q5, q4,  q4, #1    \n" 
                            "vext.16    q6, q4,  q4, #2    \n" 
            "vmovl.s32  q4, d8         \n"
            "vmovl.s32  q11, d10           \n"
            "vmovl.s32  q12, d12           \n"

                            "vmla.s32  q7, q4,  %e18[0]   \n"                           
                            "vmla.s32  q7, q11, %e18[1]   \n"
                            "vmla.s32  q7, q12, %f18[0]   \n"                              

                            "vmla.s32  q9, q4,  %e21[0]   \n"
                            "vmla.s32  q9, q11, %e21[1]   \n"

                            "vst1.s32   {d14-d15}, [%5]!   \n"
                            "vst1.s32   {d16-d17}, [%6]!   \n"
                            "vst1.s32   {d18-d19}, [%7]!   \n"
                            "vst1.s32   {d20-d21}, [%8]!   \n"

                            "add         %1, #4            \n"
                            "add         %2, #4            \n"
                            "add         %3, #4            \n"
                            "add         %4, #4            \n"
                            "subs        %0, #1            \n"
                            "bne      0b                   \n"
                            :"=r"(iOutImg_N),           // %0
                             "=r"(r0),                  // %1
                             "=r"(r1),                  // %2
                             "=r"(r2),                  // %3
                             "=r"(r3),                  // %4
                             "=r"(piOutPtr0),           // %5
                             "=r"(piOutPtr0n),          // %6
                             "=r"(piOutPtr1),           // %7
                             "=r"(piOutPtr1n)           // %8                                        
                            :"0"(iOutImg_N),
                             "1"(r0),
                             "2"(r1),
                             "3"(r2),
                             "4"(r3),
                             "5"(piOutPtr0),
                             "6"(piOutPtr0n),
                             "7"(piOutPtr1),
                             "8"(piOutPtr1n),
                             "w"(k0_0123),           // %18                      
                             "w"(k0_4567),               // %19
                             "w"(k0_8xxx),           // %20
             "w"(k1_0123),               // %21
             "w"(k1_4567),               // %22
                 "w"(k1_8xxx)          // %23                                
                            :"cc", "memory", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7", "q8" ,"q9", "q10", "q11", "q12"
```

Answer (score 2):

For vector-scalar multiplications, the 32bit scalar container must be d0 - d15 **by definition**. (It's d0 - d7 for 16bit scalars)

It's a physical limitation, and the `VTBL` instructions behave similarly.

I don't think there are more instructions with these limitations, but I may be wrong.

And besides, you should avoid using q4-q7 unless necessary anyway since they have to be preserved onto the stack prior to using and restored afterwards as defined by the `AAPCS`. Use q0-q3 instead.